# How to change XMP Toolkit MetaData in Image

Tags: metadata, exiftool, xmp

i am using exiftool to change meta data in an image. Here is a mwe:

```
#!/bin/bash
EXIF=exiftool
$EXIF -LensModel="Bubble Teleskop on Marsmission" $1
```

This is working with many entries, Model, Longitude, Latitude, etc.
But now i try to change the "XMP Toolkit" with

```
$EXIF -xmptoolkit='Paint' $1
```

or so, but every time i try to change the string, only the original name and version of the exiftool version is inserted.

Some ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I´ve found something, when i put the directive: $EXIF -Lens="XSD II 50" $1 -LensMake="Tamron" in the file, then exiftool writes the exiftool xmptoolkit string. When i omit it, then the xmptoolkit string can be changed (although the exiftool version is still written to the meta data, giving a hint to the toolkit used)

Answer (score 0):

Put all your changes on a single command:
`$EXIF -Lens="XSD II 50" -xmptoolkit='Paint' -LensMake="Tamron" $1`

Exiftool can execute multiple changes in a single command.

`XMPToolkit` is always going to get updated whenever you change some XMP data.

You can also update `XMPToolkit` as the last item in your batch or add `-tagsfromfile @ -XMPToolkit` to your commands after the command in which you set `XMPToolkit`. The `tagsfromfile @` option will recopy any tags that appear after it back into the file.